# Modify XML in SQL field stored as Varbinary

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, casting, dml

My XML is stored as varbinary in a field.

```
SELECT  cast (inboxXml as xml) FROM globalDB.Inbox WHERE inboxCId = '207435-N'
```

I would like to update one attribute (below). However the error is "Cannot call methods on varbinary(max)." I tried different ways to cast it, but I cannot find it.

thank you,

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema')
UPDATE globalDB.Inbox
SET inboxXml.modify('replace value of (//ReceiveDeliveryHeader/DocumentID/ID/@accountingEntity[.="ABC"])[1] with "ZZZ"')
WHERE inboxCId = '207435-N'
```

Answer (score 1):

The first question is: Why are you storing your XML within a `VARBINARY` column?

This is slow, clumsy and erronous...

The second thing is: `.modify()` will work against a **real native XML** only. Neither `inboxXml.modify()` nor `CAST(inboxXml AS XML).modify()` will work...

This is one more reason to change your column's type to XML...

Try this:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY,YourXml VARBINARY(MAX));

DECLARE @SomeXML XML='<root><someNode someAttr="test">content</someNode></root>';

INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES(CAST(@SomeXML AS VARBINARY(MAX)));
```

--this works

```
SELECT ID
      ,YourXml
      ,CAST(YourXml AS XML)
FROM @tbl
WHERE ID=1;
```

--but this is **not allowed**

```
UPDATE @tbl SET CAST(YourXml AS XML).modify('replace value of (/root/someNode/@someAttr)[1] with "blah"')
WHERE ID=1
```

--What you can do:

```
DECLARE @intermediateXML XML= (SELECT CAST(YourXml AS XML) FROM @tbl WHERE ID=1);
SET @intermediateXML.modify('replace value of (/root/someNode/@someAttr)[1] with "blah"');
UPDATE @tbl SET YourXml=CAST(@intermediateXML AS VARBINARY(MAX)) WHERE ID=1;

--voila!
SELECT ID
      ,YourXml
      ,CAST(YourXml AS XML)
FROM @tbl
WHERE ID=1;
```